# adding space after number in java

Tags: java, regex, string, jsp

```
 String a= request.getParameter("a");
```

I have following output

```
 out.println(a);// January 2019February 2019March 2019// prints output
```

I want the following output

```
       January 2019 February 2019 March 2019
```

i.e. adding space after the number 2019

I tried doing like this but didn't work out, any help much appreciated

```
    String a= request.getParameter("a")+"\t";// didn't work out
```

Comment: `String a = request.getParameter("a")+"\t"` just adds a tabulator at the end of the `String`. The problem is the formatting of the value returned by  `request.getParameter("a")`. Can you change that? If not, you may want to split the `String`, after every number occurrence, maybe.

Comment: I am unable to change the output actually that's why I have to format it after getting output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find all the digit-letter boundaries and replace them with a space, using [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) with this regex:

```
(\d)([A-Z])
```

and this replacement:

```
$1 $2
```

The regex captures a digit into group 1, and captures a capital letter right after that digit into group 2. We replace the digit and the letter with whatever is in group 1, followed by a space, followed by whatever is in group 2.

You can use it like this:

```
String a = request.getParameter("a").replaceAll("(\\d)([A-Z])", "$1 $2");
```

Comment: Hi thanks it worked out, just one doubt will it work in all browsers?

Comment: @Tom As far as know, JSP runs on the _server_, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: thanks a lot for help... upvoted and accepting ur ans